# Grid splitter with three columns

Tags: wpf

whenever we move the red gridsplitter it is not changing the size of the green column.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c1"  ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c2"  Width="auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c3"  Width="200"  ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c4" Width="auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="c5"    Width="200" ></ColumnDefinition>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Name="t1" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent" ></Border>
    <Border Name="t2" Grid.Column="2" Background="CadetBlue" ></Border>
    <Border Name="t3" Grid.Column="4" Background="Green" ></Border>
    <GridSplitter Name="gd1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3" ></GridSplitter>
    <GridSplitter Name="gd2" Background="red" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3"></GridSplitter>
    </Grid>

    </Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think thats what you want :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="CadetBlue"/>
    <Border Grid.Column="4" Background="Green"/>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3"/>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="3" Background="red"/>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: actually i need two columns of fixed width and one with star width

Comment: can you provide more information on what you want to get from layout?

if you want fixed size columns when you don't really need gridsplitters

Comment: i want  that my two columns of fixed width and can be resized if the user desire to make their width customized